# Build a string from a string[] without using any loops

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a string array. It is dynamic and can be of any length(**0 also**). How can I make a single string from the array, delimited by any separator like `;` or `|` ??

```
string str = string.empty;
string[] arrOptions = strOptions.Split(new string[]{"\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Now, have to make the string from `arrOptions` and put it in `str`

Comment: Thanks All. But I think I should select the first answer, that should be fair enough. ;)

Comment: :):):):) how did you determine which answer was the first?

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov : I saw from my answer notifications in inbox ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try both way:

```
    string[] strArr = { "Abc", "DEF", "GHI" };

    //    int i = 0;
    //    string final=string.Empty;
    //IterationStart:
    //    if (i < strArr.Length)
    //    {
    //        final += strArr[i] + ",";
    //        i++;
    //        goto IterationStart;
    //    }
    //Console.WriteLine(final);

     string str = string.Join(",", strArr);
     Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: commented code is another way to achieve this. yes i am using labeling.

Answer (score 5):

Use `string.Join`:

```
string result = string.Join("\n", arrOptions);
```

Or simply concat them, if you don't need the separator anymore:

```
string result = string.Concat(arrOptions);
```

Comment: Concat cannot operate dynamic numbers of string elements

Comment: @Avishek what do you mean? `public static string Concat(params string[] values)` this overload is used in this case. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Remember, I also want a separator. :/

Comment: @Avishek then it's definitely [String.Join Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Use `String.Join(separator, objects)` method.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = string.Join( ';', arrOptions );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try : `string.Join(seperator, arrOptions);`

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the below solution.

```
string str = string.empty;
string[] arrOptions = strOptions.Split(new string[]{"\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
str = string.Concat(arrOptions);
```

Thanks,

Praveen